# prove the matrix is negative semi-definite

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite, block-matrices, hermitian-matrices

Given $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=0$ and $a_i^2+b_i^2=1,\forall i\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, prove the following matrix is negative semi-definite

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
 -b_1&0&\cdots&0&0&b_1\\
 0&-b_2&\cdots&0&0&b_2\\
 \vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
    0&0&\cdots&-b_{n-1}&0&b_{n-1}\\
 0&0&\cdots&0&-b_n &b_n\\ \hline
    b_1 &b_2  &\cdots&b_{n-1}&b_n &-b_1-b_2-\cdots -b_n
 \end{array}\right]$$

Comment: I don't think so... unless you make $b_i>0$.

Comment: Like, you can explicitly write the quadratic form into the sum of (negative) squares.

Comment: What have the $a_i$ to do with anything?

Comment: @copper.hat It seems the conditions involving $a_i$ force the $b_i$ to depend on each other in a convoluted way.

Comment: [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) may be useful here; I think JetfiRex's comments are alluding to this.

Comment: If I choose $n=2, -a_1 = a_2 = b_1 = b_2 =- {1 \over \sqrt{2}}$, I get a positive semidefinite matrix.

Comment: it's necessary and sufficient to require all $b_i\geq 0$.  The $a_i$ are irrelevant.  Necessity comes because a negative semi-definite matrix cannot have a positive diagonal component (use standard basis vector and quadratic form).  For sufficiency: this is an immediate consequence of Gerschgorin Discs.